# how do I extract parts of items from a list with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I extracted some data using `find.all()`

This gives me a list with a number of strings, such as below.

```
<div class="x"><a class="x" href="x"><i class="x"></i></a> <a class="y" href="x">to make</a><span> something</span></div>
<div class="x"><a class="x" href="x"><i class="x"></i></a> <a class="y" href="x">to make</a><span> something</span></div>
<div class="x"><a class="x" href="x"><i class="x"></i></a> <a class="y" href="x">to make</a><span> something</span></div>
```

All I need is the text from `<a class ="y">`

How do I do this? Using a loop perhaps?

Comment: How does your `find_all()` call look now? I mean that you can probably find `a` tags with `class="y"` with a single `find_all()` call. Just need more information to provide you a solution.

Answer (score 2):

here's how to do it using beautiful soup:

```
>>> html= '''\
<div class="x"><a class="x" href="x"><i class="x"></i></a> <a class="y" href="x">to make</a><span> something</span></div>
<div class="x"><a class="x" href="x"><i class="x"></i></a> <a class="y" href="x">to make</a><span> something</span></div>
<div class="x"><a class="x" href="x"><i class="x"></i></a> <a class="y" href="x">to make</a><span> something</span></div>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)    
>>> list_of_y = soup.findAll("a", {'class': 'y'})
```

which returns the list of items, that you can print:

```
>>> print(list_of_y)
[<a class="y" href="x">to make</a>, <a class="y" href="x">to make</a>, <a class="y" href="x">to make</a>]
```

or iterate over:

```
>>> for y in list_of_y:
...   print(y.text)
to make
to make
to make
```

---

though, I have a little preference over lxml, which would be:

```
>>> h = etree.HTML(html)
>>> list_of_y = h.xpath('//a[@class="y"]/text()')
>>> print list_of_y
['to make', 'to make', 'to make']
>>> for y in list_of_y:
...   print(y)
... 
to make
to make
to make
```

or using CSS Selectors:

```
>>> from lxml import etree, cssselector
>>> h = etree.HTML(html)
>>> sel = cssselector.CSSSelector('a.y')
>>> list_of_y = sel(h)
>>> for y in list_of_y:
>>>     print(y.text)
```

Comment: `bs4` has css selectors too.  `soup.select('a.y')`